# Grails print Hibernate debug log in test case

Tags: hibernate, testing, grails

May I know how can I print out **Hibernate** debug log in **Grails** test case running.

I have configured in `DataSource.groovy`

```
dataSource {
    ...
    logSql = true 
}

environments {
 ... 
    test {
        dataSource {
           dbCreate = "none"
           url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/church?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
        logSql = true
         }
     hibernate {
       show_sql = true
         }
     }
 ...
}
```

and using logger to write log in test case and the controller classes, but I can't see the corresponding `Hibernate` debug log in test case console.

Please advice. Thanks !

Comment: What did you mean by 'hibernate debug log'?

Comment: Thanks! it means SQL print out and related print out trace.

Comment: I have configured 

dataSource {
   dbCreate = ...
   url = ...
   ...
   logSql = true
}
and 
log4j = {
   ...
   debug 'org.hibernate.SQL'
   trace 'org.hibernate.type'
}
and I expected to see some hibernate SQL printout when running the test cases. I can find printouts in runtime deployment but not in running test case. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you added logSql under test environment in DataSource?

Comment: I have added in test environment , but still don't have any printout.  
Please help. 

environments {
   ....
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "none"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/church?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
   logSql = true
        }
  hibernate {
   show_sql = true
  }
    }....
}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks dmahapatro. 
After I moved my test cases under test/integration folder . It works. 
I didn't notice unit test can't work with hibernate. 
Just cross checked grails documentation, it states

> The mocking support described here is best used when testing non-domain artifacts that use domain classes, to let you focus on testing the artifact without needing a database. But when testing persistence it's best to use integration tests which configure Hibernate and use a database.

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingDomains

Answer (score 0):

You could use it in unit tests if you use the HibernateSpec. The DomainUnitTest uses in memory maps, but the HibernateSpec uses hibernate and the in memory h2.
See the doc [here](https://guides.grails.org/grails-mock-basics/guide/index.html#dynamicFinderServiceTests).